# JQuery droppable problem

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I'm having trouble with the JQuery's droppable feature.
I have modified JS from here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("ul.draggable li").draggable();
    $("div.droppable").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                    alert('Hello World');
            }
    });
});
</script>

<ul class="draggable">
    <li id="one">One</li>
    <li id="two">Two</li>
    <li id="three">Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="droppable">
    <p id="round">Drop here</p>
</div>
```

The JQuery works fine if I set draggable and droppable as IDs of the HTML elements.
 However when they're classes only the draggable functionality works, the drop feature doesn't seem to do anything, and the alert function does not get executed.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Here's your sample code working: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hgsWj/ Am I not understanding the question?  Are the issues with this markup, or some other ideal markup, and if that's the case can you add it to the question?

Comment: It's this markup. Interesting how it works for you and not for me. :S

Comment: It's something with my javascript libraries... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with my JQuery libraries. Thanks Nick for testing.